# Some code working fine when executed step by step but malfunctioned when used in one go

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have used the `Range.end` property for achieving my target of setting the data into a table cell into particular number of lines.
For this first I calculate the instant cell height then keep on changing the cell width to achieve targeted cell height.

This property, when used in step by step execution, is giving the correct value, and I am able to achieve the targeted cell height. `Range.end` keeps on returning the same value even after the change in cell height, which must have changed the `range.end` value

```
'the table acted upon has 2 rows and one column and the column width as already 'set to some small value

With ActiveDocument.Tables(tableIndexTemp + 1)

'calculate cell height
posEnd = .Cell(1, 1).Range.End - 1
heightDaisRow = ActiveDocument.Range(posEnd, _ posEnd).Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary)

Do While heightDaisRow > minHeightDaisRow

'increase cell width
.Columns(1).Width = .Columns(1).Width + CentimetersToPoints(0.1)

'again calculate cell height
posEnd = .Cell(1, 1).Range.End - 1
heightDaisRow = ActiveDocument.Range(posEnd, _ posEnd).Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary)

Loop

End With
```

When executed step by step the value of `posEnd` changes with the change in width but when the same code is executed in one go the `posEnd` value does not change, which causes the cell width to keep on increasing and shows the error

> Cell width can not be more than this particular value'.

Comment: Why would you expect the value of `Range.End` to change just because the cell dimensions change? `Range.End` is the index number of the last *character* in the `Range` and has nothing to do with the position on the page. If no characters are being added within the range, the value will not change. Beyond that, it's not clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: I need to arrange a seating plan in a table row. As different names are of different length, i want to automatically adjust the width of the cells to to bring all the names in minimum possible height.

Comment: Further as you said, range.end would not change the value, the issue is likely to be caused by wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary. But i am not able to resolve the issue as what might cause act a macro differently in step by step mode or in one go mode.

Comment: Word has a setting for table cells that forces them to expand to fit their content. That is usually on by default. Word will create a new line at a space BUT if you type spaces using Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar that will insert a "non-breaking space". So Word won't move content to the next line. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But it won't help me much in my case. Actually, sometimes I need to add names or delete some names from seating plan. The macro i have written will adjust the font and number of lines in a cell to fit all the names into all the cells in uniformity keeping and keeping table within the page limits. Macro is working great but the issue only is with the use of wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary, which is causing problems in smooth functioning. Any help on use of wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary or wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage will be helpful.

Comment: i have used application.screenrefresh each time before using wdVerticalPositionRelativeToTextBoundary it seems to work fine now

Comment: Glad you found something that works :-) This is an interesting scenario and it would help the site for you to create a good answer. It should contain the solution as well as the considerations the make the approach necessary. It would also be really great if you could [edit] the question with the additional information so that someone who's looking for similar information will have all the facts. Remember to then mark your answer as "the" answer by clicking the checkmark next to (you're allowed to do that on Stack OVerflow). Ping me (using @cindymeister) when you're done it and I'll upvote!